# Grant Permission Of Microphone & Camera In MAC Catalyst In .NET MAUI Blazor Component App

Tags: macos, maui, sip, maui-blazor

I have one application which is developed in .NET MAUI Blazor Component.

It holds a SIP/VOIP functionalities.

In this application, There is functionality of video calling. So when I am running this app on windows, Its working fine and pop-up for permission of mic and camera is showing up.

[image]

But when I am trying to running same application on MAC Catalyst, The pop-up for permission of mic and camera is not showing up there.

I have tried below stuff to show above popup in MAC Catalyst. But I was not able to see popup still.

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
    .then(function(stream) {
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    });
} else {
}
```

So, My question is... How can I show this pop-up in MAC Catalyst. If there is not any way to show up this, Then how can I programmatically grant permission of mic & camera in MAC Catalyst.

Comment: Have you set the  NSCameraUsageDescription  and  NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key in info.plist?

Comment: @Liqun Shen-MSFT
Yes, I have tried it. But I was still at same situation.

Comment: May I ask what the version of macOS is?

Comment: @Liqun Shen-MSFT
Name : MAC70, Chip : Apple M1, Version : MACOS Ventura 13.2

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the app and install it again (don't forget to add two key in info.plst)? Because the permission will only show once at the first time we install it.

Comment: @Liqun Shen-MSFT
These lines are added in info.plst : `<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your camera to capture photos or videos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your microphone to record audio.</string>`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. These two keys should be added into the info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we should first add `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`.

Also, please add the [AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to show the prompt. Consider the following code:

```
//if want to show microphone prompt, you could use AVAuthorizationMediaType.Audio
AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType (AVAuthorizationMediaType.Video, (bool isPermissionGranted) => 
{                                
    if(isPermissionGranted)
    {
  
    }
    else
    {
  
    }
});
```

Then the prompt should show. For more info, you could refer to [requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccessformediatype?language=objc)

By the way, the prompt will show at the first time after app is installed. The os will remember the user's response so subsequent uses of the capture system don’t cause the prompt to appear again.

Hope it works.
[image]

Comment: It's working. But only in iOS, Which is used in mobile devices. This snippet is not working on MAC Catalyst.

Comment: Have you also add the two key to the Platforms/MacCatalyst/info.plist?

Comment: Yes I did the changes for it.

Comment: Try clean the project, delete the app and reopen vs. I add a picture that from my demo, is it what you want ?

Comment: The solution worked for me. Thanks for the support. Now I am having one more problem. I want to share the screen on the MAC using [sipjs](https://sipjs.com/). I have tried by using [electronjs API](https://www.electronjs.org/) `desktopCapturer.getSources()` & `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` APIS. But the pop-up for screen sharing is not opening on the MAC app. Note that, Its working for the Windows app.

Comment: I recommend starting a new thread with more detailed information. You may also add sipjs and electronjs tags for your new question. Let more people see your question and help you.

Comment: Already did. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454436/open-screensharing-popup-in-the-mac-catalyst-app).

Comment: Thanks. And I think maui blazor tag is also necessary.